# Finding the slope of a curve with inverse trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves

I'm having some issues with the following problem:

**Find the slope of the curve $\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)=\frac{\pi{}x}{y^2}}$ at the point $(1, 2)$.**

Since I'm looking for the slope I want to differentiate the function of the curve, and to do that I re-wrote it as: $\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)=\frac{\pi{}x}{y^2}} \Leftrightarrow {tan}^{-1}{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)-\frac{\pi{}x}{y^2}=0}$.

By letting $f(x)=\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)-\frac{\pi{}x}{y^2}}$, I now can differentiate $f(x)$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1+{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)}^2}\times{}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\pi{}x}{y^2}\right)=\frac{1}{1+{\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)}^2}\times{}\left(\frac{2}{y}\right)-\left(\frac{\pi{}}{y^2}\right)$$

Finally, I can replace $x$ and $y$ with 1 and 2, and after simplifying the expresion I end up with $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi{}}{4}$, but the answer should be $\frac{\pi{}-2}{\pi{}-1}$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: When you did the derivatives of the terms containing $y$ you forgot to use the chain rule. [That is, $y$ is not a constant but a function of $x$ so chain rule needed.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work looks okay. Here is what I have.

Note that
$$
f(x,y)\equiv 0 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0 \tag1
$$
Doing the calculus I get
$${{2}\over{\left({{4\,x^2}\over{y^2}}+1\right)\,y}}-{{\pi}\over{y^2
 }}+\left({{2\,\pi\,x}\over{y^3}}-{{2\,x}\over{\left({{4\,x^2}\over{
 y^2}}+1\right)\,y^2}}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=0\tag2$$

Do the substitutions to get 
$$\left({{\pi}\over{4}}-{{1}\over{4}}\right)\,\frac{dy}{dx}-{{\pi}\over{4}}+{{1
 }\over{2}}=0$$
which gives the answer you want.

Comment: How the OP's work "looks okay" if he didn't differentiate implicitly correctly??

Answer (score 1):

Why not implicitly differentiating directly without messy notation?:

$$\frac2{y\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{y^2}\right)}dx-\frac{2x}{y^2\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{y^2}\right)}dy=\frac\pi{y^2}dx-\frac{2\pi x}{y^3}dy\implies$$

$$\left(\frac2{y\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{y^2}\right)}-\frac\pi{y^2}\right)dx=\frac{2x}{y^2}\left(\frac1{1+\frac{4x^2}{y^2}}-\frac\pi y\right)dy\implies$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(1,2)=\left(\frac2{2\left(1+\frac{4}{4}\right)}-\frac\pi{4}\right)\cdot\frac1{\frac{2}{4}\left(\frac1{1+\frac{4}{4}}-\frac\pi 2\right)}=$$

$$=\left(\frac12-\frac\pi4\right)\frac1{\frac12\left(\frac12-\frac\pi2\right)}=\left(1-\frac\pi2\right)\frac2{1-\pi}=\frac{2-\pi}{1-\pi}$$